# Direct login link get unaccessible for email recipients

Tags: php, email, url

We have a customer questionnaire that we send with a email link to our customers. The link to the questionnaire (secure web form) is sent to each customer in a plain text email (encoding: UTF-8) containing a unique link with the form:

```
https://www.domain.com/form/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where the identifier `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` consist of a combination of the characters `abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwyxz-_23456789` - should be valid URI characters (unreserved) that I know of (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.3 for reference).

The problem is that apparently quite many recipients are unable to access the link successfully, it seem to get somewhat scrambled (there should be no linebreak involved). They get to an 404 page within the site we're using but doesn't get logged in to answer the questionnaire as wanted.

Is there any best practices for sending links that we have foreseen? Any suggestions how to make links accessible for most users?

**UPDATE**

I have now set up logging (which wasn't present in a good way before) and removed `-_`from the used identifier characters and will try to do some furher debugging to see if any of your suggested answers would help. Other answers/comments appreciated!

Comment: Rather than use an identifier as part of the URL, why aren't you using a $_GET sequence?  That is the purpose of $_GET.

Comment: have you tried `ulrencode` on the identifier string?

Comment: Check your server's logs. They'll show EXACTLY what the requested url was for the 404s, and you'll be able to see where the url "broke". e.g. mangled/missing characters, truncated sequence, etc...

Comment: @SableFoste What should be the problem of having it as part of the URI? I'm using CodeIgniter as the backend so accessing URI segments are very easy.

Comment: @LiamAllan But `urlencode()` should do nothing with a string of "unreserved characters"?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the dash (`-`) character, and the link is long enough, I know for a fact that many email clients will use it to break the line at that point. And after that, when they transform text that looks like a link into clickable links, they will only use the first part.

My solution was to avoid the dash character, and it did help with issues, but I am not 100% that's the only thing in play here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for replying. However the link is never more than around 50 characters and is always printed on a new line, so there should be no reason for the line to break anyway? I will however try to see if that could be the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it could be an encoding issue. Are you able to log the requests coming into the web server?

That was you may have a better idea as to where the issue is steming from.

Comment: Good suggestion, I will check and try to log the requests.

Comment: Assuming only latin characters are used, there should be no encoding issues since they are common to all character sets.

Comment: No but 'if' the email is sent out in html, there could be an error in the markup causing it to error.

Comment: As written the emails are sent in plain text format. Encoding is UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

In one project I worked in we decided to use the PHP (5.4.0+) function [hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) to create a unique ID for verify the user mail address.

Using $salt as a random characters to generate the hash and the $user_mail to create a unique ID:

```
        $salt = '~Z!@#$%I^&*()_-+Q=}]{[\|"><';
        $unique_ID = hash('sha256', $user_mail . $salt);
```

You will get a 64 bit string like:

```
2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e730
```

The string has no especial chars, so the link will don't break in some mail/SO clients. (see this [article](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/et020306.htm) about 'How to Prevent Mac OS X Mail From Breaking Links in Emails')

Remember to check if the $user_mail exists in the DB before you create the unique_id.

Comment: In the same article you can see that ´Mac OS X Mail will break any line 70 characters or longer, destroying the link for some email programs´.

Comment: Thank you for the provided information. However the links are always alone on a separate line and has about 50 characters, no more. I will try to start logging to see if I can find some apparent problems!